# run code after window open javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, popupwindow

I need to call `window.open()` to open a popup to show PDF file and then delete the file once it is shown. But i need to do that in code behind for security purpose.

But when I call `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` in `Page_Load()`, and the `File.Delete` in `Page_LoadComplete`, the file in deleted before the loading in popup!

Have you any idea how to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `But i need to do that in code behind for security purpose.` Can you talk us through the security concern? When you say you are deleting the file do you mean deleting it on the client or on the server?

Comment: once the pdf is generated, it is saved on the server. Then i call window.opn to show it. Then i call file.delete to delete it. a user have not to be able to access to the "delete" code, because he can stop it and the file remains in the server. So i have to put the "delete" code on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be one recipe:

- Instead of calling `window.open('mypdf.pdf');` call `window.open('pdfprocessor.aspx?id=<Some identifier>');`
- In `pdfprocessor.aspx` you get the `byte[]` from the pdf file.
- Remove the file.
- Reponse.Write that `byte[]`.